# Opsview: Use a service multiple times with different arguments

Tags: linux, monitoring, nagios, opsview

I'm currently having a look at Opsview, which looks quiet good.
I downloaded the virtual appliance to make some tests and at the
moment I'm a bit stuck on a part which I considered to be very easy.

I want to define a service check, which takes a parameter ($ARG1$).
This service should now be assigned to a host serveral times, but with
different values for the parameter.

Is this possible with Opsview?
I even was not able to define a service check with a parameter and
then specifie this parameter.
In the end I choose "Exception" and then substituted there the
parameter $ARG1$ with my desired value.
That could not be the right way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're nearly correct.

From the [OpsView documentation](http://docs.opsview.org/doku.php?id=opsview3.1:exceptions&s[]=exceptions)

> It is possible at the host or the host
>   template selection screen for services
>   to monitor to make an exception for
>   the arguments passed to the plugin.
>
> Just enter the new arguments within
>   the text field and when an Opsview
>   reload is run, these arguments will be
>   used instead of the default ones in
>   the service check definition.

So, you add your arguments as the exception and they are used instead of those specified in the service check definition.